# jQuery.post refreshes my page?

Tags: jquery, forms, refresh

I have the following code with a form on my page. But when I click submit, it seemed like my page refreshes.

form:

```
<form action='#' method='post'>
    <div><input type='text' name='name' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Save' /></div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').bind('submit',function() {
            var str = $('form').serialize();

            $.post("save.php", { formString: str }, 
                function(data) {
                    alert("Saved: " + data);
                }
            );

        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set a

```
return false;
```

to your form (for example on the onSubmit). Your form is sended by both jQuery ($.post) and the page itself, because you do not stop it to do that. Another option (works the same) is to let the jquery-part disable the default behaviour of your form:

```
//your code
$('form').bind('submit',function() {
   // more of your code
   return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Snicksie, but where do I put return false;?

Comment: I recommend to use the second part of code I gave you, but if you prefer the 'return false;', put it here: `<form action="#" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" >`

Comment: apparently you'll need to let your function return false. I'll change that in my answer.