# MVC AJAX POST request redirects to originating page as GET

Tags: c#, json, ajax, post, model-view-controller

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction with this, have been scratching my head all day over it and am developing a bald spot. I have spent a lot of time on SO, but none of the questions I found seemed to pertain to my exact problem.

Briefly, I have a dropdown list and want to give users the ability to add entries to the list in realtime. I intended on using AJAX to send form info to a controller whereupon it would be entered into the table, re-queried and then delivered back to the page as a JSON array whereupon I would parse it and replace the data in the Select dropdown.

However, what happens is that the POST request occurs, and at some point during the data processing the page refreshes and the data is appended to the URL as a GET request.

The AJAX request:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save-new-range", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var loc = window.location.href;
    var url = stripURL('Data/addRange', loc); // Format the target URL correctly

    $.post(url, $("#add-range-form").serialize())
        .done(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response);
    });
});
```

StripURL function (just in case!)

```
function stripURL(url, loc) {
var res = "";

if (loc.search("Surveys/New") !== -1) {
    res = loc.replace("Surveys/New", "");
} else if (loc.search("Surveys/Amend") !== -1) {
    res = loc.replace("Surveys/Amend", "");
} else if (loc.search("Surveys/") !== -1) {
    res = loc.replace("Surveys/Amend", "");
}


if (res.search("#") !== -1) {
    res = res.replace("#", "");
}

url = res + url;

return url;
}
```

The Controller(without the queries and inserts):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult addRange(FormCollection fc)
{
    {
    ... Do data processing and query data into a dictionary called res ...
    }
    return Json(res);
}
```

Debugging, My controller actions are processed and res is populated with the correct data, but the .done() function is never entered due to the redirect.

Am happy to post the full controller, but have left it out for the sake of brevity. Let me know if you want to see it.

Comment: Try adding a 'return false' in your .on("click" per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524971/jquery-post-refreshes-my-page

Comment: Try `preventDefault()` with the function call `()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#save-new-range", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var loc = window.location.href;
    var url = stripURL('Data/addRange', loc); // Format the target URL correctly

    $.post(url, $("#add-range-form").serialize())
        .done(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response);
    });

    return false;
});
```

See if this does the trick.

Comment: Yeah that did it. Been banging my head against a brick wall all day for the sake of two little words! Thanks very much dood.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `e.preventDefault` without calling it as a function. This will not run. That is why `return false;` works as in the accepted answer. Using `e.preventDefault()` as a function call would not require the `return false;`.

```
$(document).on("click", "#save-new-range", function (e) {

    // called as a function
    e.preventDefault();

    var loc = window.location.href;
    var url = stripURL('Data/addRange', loc); // Format the target URL correctly

    $.post(url, $("#add-range-form").serialize())
        .done(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response);
    });
});
```

You can test this in the console of SO like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will stop any `a` tag from it's default behavior. If you leave out the function call it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll make sure to take this into account in the future.